# How to import a variable when using "require"?

Tags: perl, variables, import, require, perl-module

This doesn't work (error messages below). How could I make this work?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use 5.10.1;

sub routine {
    require FindBin;
    FindBin::->import( '$RealBin' );
    say $RealBin;
}

routine();
```

Gives this output

```
Global symbol "$RealBin" requires explicit package name at ./perl.pl line 9.
Execution of ./perl.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `require` and `import` happen at runtime, whereas variables have to be declared at compile time. So we have three solutions:

1. Import `FindBin` at compile time:

   ```
   use FindBin qw/$RealBin/;

   sub routine {
       say $RealBin;
   }
   ```

   I strongly suggest this solution.
2. Declare the variable so that it can be used without `strict` or `warnings` complaining:

   ```
   sub routine {
       require FindBin;
       FindBin->import('$RealBin');
       our $RealBin;  # this just declares it so we can use it from here on
       say $RealBin;
   }
   ```
3. Don't import the symbol and use the fully qualified name instead:

   ```
   sub {
       require FindBin;
       # FindBin->import;  # does nothing here
       say $FindBin::RealBin;
   }
   ```

Loading `FindBin` at runtime is probably useless from a performance perspective, and you should just `use` it normally. If you are doing these weird run-time gymnastics to calculate the `$RealBin` anew at each call of `routine`, none of these solutions will work because `require` does not execute the module if it has already been loaded (it does something like `$INC{'FindBin.pm'} or return`). The `FindBin::again` function might help instead.

- [`FindBin` docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/FindBin)
- [`require` docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html)

Comment: With `warnings` enabled adding `no warnings 'once'` to the third example would suppress the `used only once` warning.